# Perform search on an array inside of object Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, search

I am trying to perform search on brands of this remotes array. can anyone help please?

```
this.remotes = [
      {programmintool: "Smart Pro", notes: 'Remote has a inbuild chip', brands:['TOYOTA', 'FIAT']},
      {programmintool: "Smart Pro", notes: 'Remote has a inbuild chip', brands:['FORD','NISSAN']}];

funtion _ionChange(event){
    const val = event.target.value;

    this.searchedItem = this.remotes;
    
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.searchedItem = this.searchedItem.filter((item: any) => {
        return (item.brands.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: you need to return `item.brands.findIndex(elem => elem.toLowerCase() === val.toLowerCase()) > -1`

Comment: it worked!! Thank you